# Help in visual studio vs google / bing

Tags: .net, visual-studio

When in visual studio and wanting some information, why does simply dropping out to a browser massively out perform the compiled help system or context sensitive help.  MS put so much resource into documenting .NET. Why don't they simply put a bing box and bing context senstive help into visual studio.

Comment: On my relatively old dev box, the compiled help takes ages to load, and locks out VS while it is loading; it is much quicker to google.

Comment: They probably auto-generate the local documentation with the same tools they use to generate the MSDN, so the "cost" of creating the documentation is probably very low. And they **have** to generate the MSDN because it's the "true" reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Google and Bing do provide fantastic answers most of the time, there are instances when they're not going to be available so offline documentation must be provided.

The documentation will be written by the team that develops the program who will be relatively few compared to the thousands of users online who are using it, blogging about it and asking and answering questions here.

You cant ever hope to have your documentation for something as complex as visual studio cover the wealth of scenarios and edge cases that could occur.  It has to fit on the install media after all.  Google and Bing have every site on the internet they've indexed to draw from, so your search has terabytes of relevant information to be digested and the odds of your particular scenario being covered are much greater.